# Simulation showing different results for a same practical case

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, voltage, current, diodes

Below I have this simulation.

The diodes represent the clamping diodes placed inside the microcontroller GPIO pins.

Case 1 - Given directly using the voltage source.

[image]

Case 2 - Given the same voltage through a resistor divider.

[image]

In the above image, both the circuits are providing 12V at the GPIO pin. But first one is given through the voltage source. Second is through a resistor divider network. But effectively, same voltage is given and provide at the GPIO pin. But we are getting different results.

I understand that in the first case, since the Voltage source output is very low impedance, it is showing 12V. But I am confused on this behaviour and unable to arrive at a conclusion on how the 2 cases are different. Please help to provide an answer in simple terms for my clarity.

Comment: In your first circuit, the diode will burn immediately.  But in the second case, the diode current is now equal to around (12V - 5V)/500  = 14mA thus, it will survive and this is why you have 5.7V at the input.

Comment: It is not very low impedance, it is an ideal voltage source, so it has no impedance. Any node you connect it to will be forced to have that voltage.

Comment: Yes. I understand your reasons for the answers. But I am stuck with this line - The voltage at GPIO pin @ both the cases are the same 12V. So, why do we get different results.

Comment: The voltage is 5.77794 volts and not 12 volts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The voltage at GPIO pin @ both the cases are the same 12V

No it isn't, in the second case the voltage is 5.7V.

The important thing to understand about resistance dividers is that they are *not* voltage regulators; with nothing else connected you achieve a specific voltage. When you connect something which draws current from the middle, then the current in the resistors is now *different*, and as a result they take on different voltage values.

It may become clearer if you try, for example:

- measure the current at various points in the circuit. What current is travelling through each resistor? What current is through the diode?
- putting a 1 ohm resistor between the "direct" supply and the pin. Vary this upwards - try 100R and 1K. This will reduce the voltage at the pin without explicitly having a resistor divider; the diode is effectively acting as the other "leg" of the divider.